# Filtrar Textos diferentes no R

Tags: r

Boa tarde,
Tenho os seguintes dados:

```
NOME  <- c("LEITO 1001", "LEITO 1002", "LEITO 1003", "LEITO 50", "LEITO 60")
VALOR <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
dados <- data.frame(NOME, VALOR)
```

Necessito filtrar apenas os Leitos `"LEITO 1001"`, `"LEITO 1002"` e `"LEITO 1003"`. Gostaria da ajuda como proceder. Há alguma alternativa utilizando a função `for`?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O operador lógico `%in%` é muito útil nessas situações para te evitar escrever diversas comparações com `|` (ou). Exemplo usando `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dados <- dados %>%
  filter(NOME %in% paste("LEITO", c(1001:1003)))


dados

        NOME VALOR
1 LEITO 1001    10
2 LEITO 1002    20
3 LEITO 1003    30
```

Comment: Bom dia. Infelizmente não deu certo, uma vez que o meu exemplo não foi o melhor.

Comment: Abrirei uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Alguns argumentos lógicos da linguagem R para filtrar dados são importantes de conhecer:

`!x` => não x

`x | y` => x OU y

`x & y` => x E y

`isTRUE(x)` => testar se X é TRUE

Filtrar os dados com multiplas condições pode ser realizado de diferente maneiras:

```
dados
        NOME VALOR
1 LEITO 1001    10
2 LEITO 1002    20
3 LEITO 1003    30
4 LEITO   50    40
5 LEITO   60    50
```

usando `which()`:

```
dados[which(dados$NOME == "LEITO 1001" | dados$NOME == "LEITO 1002" | dados$NOME == "LEITO 1003"),]
```

Usando a função `subset()`:

```
subset(dados, NOME == "LEITO 1001" | NOME == "LEITO 1002" | NOME == "LEITO 1003")
```

Usando `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(dados, NOME == "LEITO 1001" | NOME == "LEITO 1002" | NOME == "LEITO 1003")
```

Usando `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT *
      FROM dados 
      WHERE NOME == "LEITO 1001" OR NOME == "LEITO 1002" OR NOME == "LEITO 1003"')
```

Resultado:

```
        NOME VALOR
1 LEITO 1001    10
2 LEITO 1002    20
3 LEITO 1003    30
```